# PHP conditions depending on window width (media queries?)

Tags: php, media-queries, conditional-statements

I have a responsive website and I need some PHP conditions depending on the windows width (or media queries).

Example:

```
if ($window_width > 1400px) {
    echo 'Your window is wider than 1400px';
}

elseif ($window_width > 1000px) AND ($window_width < 1399px) {
    echo 'Your window is between 1000px and 1399px';
}

else {
    echo 'Your window is narrower than 1000px.';
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think you can do that as PHP runs on the server not on the client. Why don't you use simple CSS @media query? Or even Javascript?

Comment: I need different PHP scripts running depending on the window width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check this

[Goolgle Mobile Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect)

Try to use http://www.php.net/get_browser and check for isMobileDevice field. It might help only, of course, if the path to browscap.ini is set up in php.ini. If not, you can use php classes like https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap

Comment: That doesn’t help out because I also need the script detect when only the windows is resized on a desktop.

Comment: then you can help of this code http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: Ah, sometimes the solution can be so easy! The utility classes work in my case—thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Nope you can not do it with php.
php is strictly  server side

user javascript instead.
Below is my code to get device resolution using javascript

```
<script>
     screenWidth = window.screen.width,
     screenHeight = window.screen.height;
    console.log(screenWidth);
    console.log(screenHeight);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In views you can show/hide divs, something like this:

```
<style>
    #web {display: block;}
    #mobile {display: none;}

    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        #web {display: none;}
        #mobile {display: block;}
    }
</style>

<div id="mobile">
    <?php echo "is mobile"; //include("page_mobile.phtml"); ?>
</div>

<div id="web">
    <?php echo "is web"; //include("page_web.phtml"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it doesn't matter that the PHP is processed first.  The css will take over before it's rendered anyway so it avoids the ugly show/hide after page load if you rely on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for device detection. I'm not sure if you can detect window width using PHP alone. If you can then this information would appear in the HTTP headers. I would recommend using an open source PHP class built for this: http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: That doesn’t help out because I also need the script detect when only the windows is resized on a desktop.

Comment: Then you are looking at the wrong technology. PHP is executed on the server side. You could use CSS media queries to achieve this. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I know media queries for CSS, but I need different PHP scripts to be executed depending on the window width and that’s not possible with pure CSS media queries.

Comment: PHP is not the right technology for this. If you want something to happen on the client side, i.e. if a user resizes their browser window, you need to use client side technology. CSS media queries, or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick:
Evaluate the window width with js, then load your PHP in a frame and put the width in a parameter. Your PHP script then can read that parameter and perform different conditions depending on that value.

Here is the js part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    document.write('<iframe src="content.php?w='+width+'"></iframe>');
</script>
```

Within your content.php file just read the width parameter and do something with it:

```
<?php
    //Get width of browser window
    $width = $_GET['w'];
    echo ('width: '.$width);
?>
```